# How to delay a for loop execution in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, timeout, promise

As the title states, I need to delay each iteration of a for loop.  Here is what I have found of several of Stack Overflow posts:

```
var my_event_num = $(this).data('eventnum');

for (var i = 0; i < motion_media[my_event_num].length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $("#slideshow-" + my_event_num).attr('src', 'motion-media/' + motion_media[my_event_num][index]) 
        }, 2000);
    })(i);
}
```

`motion_media` - an array of arrays. `my_event_num` - a valid pointer to an index in `motion_media`.

However, this (and several other solutions) didn't work for me - it immediately executes the entire for loop with no timeout.  Would recursion be the way to go?  How could I implement such a solution?

Comment: may be this link help you http://scottiestech.info/2014/07/01/javascript-fun-looping-with-a-delay/

Comment: I hope it helps http://jsfiddle.net/planet260/j88ocfh8/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
var my_event_num = $(this).data('eventnum');

for (var i = 0; i < motion_media[my_event_num].length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $("#slideshow-" + my_event_num).attr('src', 'motion-media/' + motion_media[my_event_num][index]) 
        }, 2000*i);
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would recursion be the way to go?

Yes, using pseudo-recursion is an easy and probably the best solution.

```
var my_event_num = $(this).data('eventnum');
(function go(index) {
    if (i < motion_media[my_event_num].length) {
        $("#slideshow-" + my_event_num).attr('src', 'motion-media/' + motion_media[my_event_num][index]);
        setTimeout(function() {
            go(i+1);
        }, 2000);
    }
}(0));
```

However, you did ask about promises as well. Using the [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and [`promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) animation queue methods of jQuery, you can devise a similarly easy promise sequence:

```
var my_event_num = $(this).data('eventnum');
var promise = $.when();
for (var i = 0; i < motion_media[my_event_num].length; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        return $("#slideshow-" + my_event_num)
          .attr('src', 'motion-media/' + motion_media[my_event_num][index])
          .delay(2000)
          .promise();
    });
}
```